# Reprinted or Adapted?

Tags: tables

After what type of changes must a table be considered as adapted instead of reprinted? If I reproduce a part of a table in my text (by making my own table and inserting the info) and correct some spelling mistakes, will that make it adapted instead of reprinted?

Answer (score 3):

To reprint normally implies to republish something in an unaltered form from the original. In principle, therefore, any change is an adaptation of the original. If you correct an error, it could be listed as a “reprint with corrections,” but then the corrections need to be specified. Otherwise, it’s adapted.

Answer (score 1):

For figures, “reprinted” (or “reproduced”)  would be unmodified and “adapted” would mean the figure has seen some changes (aesthetic, axis cropping, etc.)

For tables, though, it is less clear because you are presenting data and not a graphical object (drawing, picture, graph, etc.). If you use the table as it was originally published, “reproduced” is definitely the right term. If you merely fix spelling mistakes, “reproduced (with typos corrected)” is probably also very clear.

If, however, you create you own table by taking the existing data, adding some other information, you need to be much **more precise and indicate what data is yours and what comes from previous reference(s)**. Depending on how much data there is and how much is modified, I can see two strategies that work well:

- indicate in the caption that *“Columns A, B, and C are reproduced from Ref. X (with typos fixed).”*
- if the layout is more complex, italicise the original data: *“Data in italics is taken from Ref. X”.*